# The type initializer for 'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.SharedIcons' threw an exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I have created SSIS package an year ago in VS2012. I am trying to open it now in VS 2012 only and I get **error: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.SharedIcons' threw an exception.**

I googled the error and solutions suggested was to install CU4 and CU5. I tried both and didnt work. Please hep me with this.

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Data Tools installed on this machine?

Comment: Yes! I have SSDT installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download and install Cumulative Update 14 for SQL Server 2012 SP1
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3023636

Answer (score 1):

After some exercise,

- Uninstalling SQL server 2012
- Re installing SQL server 2012
- And applying CU4 and CU5

I was able to open SSIS package   .

This [link has an explanation an important informationabout this problem](http://www.mssqlgirl.com/vs2012-ultimate-ssis-start-up-error.html).